# Как сделать кнопку назад в Laravel Blade?

Tags: php, laravel

Нашел ответ 3 летней давности где  предлагается использовать

```
session()->previousUrl();
```

Правильно ли использовать эту функцию  , или есть  другие решения ?

Answer (score 1):

Ну скажем, нет ничего неправильного в ее использовании, раз уж она есть и не имеет статус `deprecated`.
Я же использую `{{ url()->previous() }}`, также имеет место `{{ URL::previous() }}` есть и еще способы, но они уже совсем извращенные.
А вообще в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/urls) неплохо описано

Comment: Имеет ли смысл использовать  javascript  для  кнопки назад

Comment: Но если уж у вас страница полностью генерируется через js то смысл есть... но для этого есть window.history.back()

Answer (score 1):

Можно и так

```
{{back()->getTargetUrl()}}
```